# Is there any way to store list in database in django?

Tags: python, django, list, sqlite

[This is the list I have to insert in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F9CA.png)

[This is the error I got while inserting in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9pZL.png)

[This is my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBIj.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Postgres db then you have access to ArrayField:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Other then that... You can for example store students ids as ManytoMany field

Comment: Is there any other way to insert it without using Postgres db? Can't it be done without having to install new dependencies or by using bulk_update_or_create ?

Comment: You can store it in TextField and then extract it somehow, but I highly NOT recommend it. What db are you using?

Comment: I m using default database provided by django, SQLite 3

Comment: SQLite is very limited db. It's good for MVP. I recommend moving to Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Update marks to be an ArrayField.

```
marks = models.ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default= [], blank=False, null=False)
```

then you can initialize the new object just fine. if you need to update the array after the object's creation, you can do that like so:

```
result.marks = [0,90]
result.save()
```

Comment: Be careful with the default. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) when using `[]` as default all instances of the `ArrayField` will share the data. To create independent `ArrayField`s use the `default=list`.

Comment: absolutely, my mistake. default should be default=list

Comment: But this is possible only when I use PostgresDB and  currently, I am using SQLite 3

Comment: what Bartosz Stasiak is true, i recommend the switch to Postgres as well